# Prove, by induction on m.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove, by induction on $m$, that for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb P^n(\varnothing)\subseteq \mathbb{P^{n+m}}(\varnothing).$

$\mathbb{P}$ - is a power set.

Prove: $\mathbb{P}^n(\varnothing) \subseteq \mathbb{P}(\mathbb P^{n}(\varnothing))=\mathbb P^{n+1}(\varnothing)$, (we can assume that, we don't need to prove it).

Assume $\mathbb P^{n}(\varnothing)\subseteq \mathbb P^{m}(\mathbb P^{n}(\varnothing))=\mathbb P^{n+m}(\varnothing)$,

Then $\mathbb P^{n}(\varnothing)\subseteq \mathbb{P}(\mathbb P^{m}(\mathbb P^{n}(\varnothing)))=\mathbb P^{n+m+1}(\varnothing)$

Am I doing it right?

Comment: Why can you assume that $\wp^n(\varnothing)\subseteq\wp^{n+1}(\varnothing)$? If it’s because you’ve already proved it for all $n\in\Bbb N$, or if you’ve been told to assume it, that’s fine, but otherwise you do need to prove it.

Comment: I proved it already. So you can assume it.